# Converting datetime to date and time only

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I am concatenating 2 columns in SQL Server, they both have a data type of `datetime`:

```
UPDATE dbo.Feban_stg 
SET [Date & Time Posted] = CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date Posted], 110), RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, [Time Posted], 100), 7))
```

and so far I always get this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The datatype of date & time posted is datetime as well.

Thanks

Comment: Convert your update into a select first to see what your concat actually creates. Probably the output is not in the culture specific datetime format used on your SQL server.

Comment: 1900-01-01 17:30:00.000
1900-01-01 17:34:00.000
1900-01-01 18:06:00.000

@JennyO'Reilly this is the output

Comment: Please, provide the sample of `dbo.Feban_stg` table.

Comment: Let's say I have 3 columns, Date Posted, Time Posted and Date and Time posted so basically Date and time posted column is just the concatenated column for date posted and time posted. @gofr1

Comment: Well... for example `[Date Posted] 2016-03-17 [Time Posted] 15:48:01.000` like this?

Comment: @gofr1 `[Date Posted] 2016-02-02 17:35:02 [Time Posted] 1899-12:30 18:06:32` this is the sample output

Comment: What happens if you want to set the new column to a static value like `'1900-01-01 17:30:00.000'`? I guess that produces the same error.

Comment: I tried to reproduce error here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36853/4 and it gaves me `02-02-2016 6:06PM` as result

Comment: @gofr1 could you please try to update the [Date and Time Posted] column with the output? I don't know if what was wrong with my code.

Comment: @christinaG What is [Date & Time Posted] column data type?

Comment: @Balde datetime as well.

Comment: On my SQL Server your code works fine. Try `RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, [Time Posted], 120), 9)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is not space between the date part and time part. CANCAT just adds strings. Try this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Feban_stg 
SET [Date & Time Posted] = CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date Posted], 110), ' ', RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, [Time Posted], 100), 8))
```

In addition, you need 8 instead 7 in RIGHT function to get the complete hour.

Comment: That's odd, because in the examples @christinaG posted there are spaces between the date and time parts.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly the problem was in the result string of concatenating the date part of [Date Posted] and the time part of [Time Posted].